# ABTableViewCell Height

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm using ABTableViewCell by atebits: http://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

The one thing I can't figure out is how to change the height of the cell. Due to the drawing method, I don't think it responds to the normal methods that I've found for changing the height of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UITableView handles the cell heights. Either with the `rowHeight` property or the delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The ABTableViewCell responds as any other cell does to these methods.